# How to match default TabPage styles with programaticlaly created tab pages?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, tabpage

When inserting tabpages programmatically, the TabPages that are created do not have the same type of color-scheme as one would expect when using the designer.  As you can see from the screenshot image below, the "Active" tab's background color has remained unchanged.  How would I programmatically add TabPages to a tab-control so it would behave as if I had added them using the designer?

[image]

I have the following code that programmatically inserts tab-pages onto a tab control I have created using WinForms (it is in a foreach loop).

```
TabPage tPage = new TabPage();
tPage.Text = item.DisplayName + " Options";

FlowLayoutPanel flowPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
Label lblLocationField = new Label();
lblLocationField.Text = "Insert into location field:";
CheckBox chkLocationField = new CheckBox();
chkLocationField.Name = "locationField";
flowPanel.Controls.Add(lblLocationField);
flowPanel.Controls.Add(chkLocationField);

tPage.Controls.Add(flowPanel);

this.tabControlConfiguration.Controls.Add(tPage);
```

Comment: Check out the designer file and copy all the properties that it sets on the tabPage before adding it.  Should be some display options in there such as BackColor.

Comment: - or - you can forget winforms and use WPF, which allows you to set application-wide styles and templates for any UI elements.

Comment: You are probably seeing the FlowLayoutPanel.  Yes, by default its BackColor is gray.  Change it.  The code and the screenshot don't match very well.

Comment: @Hans Passant I removed the FlowLayoutPanel all together and it's still the same case as pictured in the original question below.

Comment: Adding to zimdanen's comment - the designer just adds code in a different place. Compare the code between yours and the .designer.cs file to find that difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, a new instance of TabPage sets the UseVisualStyleBackColor property to false by default, whereas the designer sets it to "true."

Therefore, by simply adding the one line below to my code, I was able to get it to render properly!

```
tPage.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

[image]